# Why isn't this public String function working?

Tags: java, string, function, methods, return

It is saying that it must return a string but I don't see anything wrong with it? I think numericDayOfWeek should be working fine?

```
 public String getDayOfWeek(){
         if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
             return "Saturday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==1){
             return "Sunday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==2){
             return "Monday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==3){
             return "Tuesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==4){
            return "Wednesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==5){
            return "Thursday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==6){
             return "Friday";
         }
     }
```

Here is the full code

```
public class DayOfWeek {
    int myMonth, myDayOfMonth, myYear, myAdjustment, numericDayOfWeek;

    public DayOfWeek(int month, int dayOfMonth, int  year){
        myMonth = month;
        myDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
        myYear = year;
    }
    public int getNumericDayOfWeek(){
        if(myMonth==1){
            myAdjustment = 1;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment-=1;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==2){
            myAdjustment = 4;
            if(myYear%4==0){
                myAdjustment-=1;
            }
        }
        if(myMonth==3){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==4){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==5){
            myAdjustment = 2;
        }
        if(myMonth==6){
            myAdjustment = 5;
        }
        if(myMonth==7){
            myAdjustment = 0;
        }
        if(myMonth==8){
            myAdjustment = 3;
        }
        if(myMonth==9){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        if(myMonth==10){
            myAdjustment = 1;
        }
        if(myMonth==11){
            myAdjustment = 4;
        }
        if(myMonth==12){
            myAdjustment = 6;
        }
        int fourDivides = myYear / 4;
        numericDayOfWeek = myAdjustment + myDayOfMonth + (myYear-1900) + fourDivides; 
        return numericDayOfWeek;

    }
     public String getDayOfWeek(){
         if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
             return "Saturday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==1){
             return "Sunday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==2){
             return "Monday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==3){
             return "Tuesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==4){
            return "Wednesday";
         }
        if(numericDayOfWeek==5){
            return "Thursday";
         }
         if(numericDayOfWeek==6){
             return "Friday";
         }
     }
     public int getMonth(){

     }
     public String getMonthString(){

     }
     public int getDayOfMonth(){

     }
     public int getYear(){

     }

}
```

Comment: instead of `if..then` you should use `switch`, so you avoid doing 7 comparison in the worst case (for method `getDayOfWeek`), or at lease `if..then..else` because they are exclusives.

Comment: What will the function return if none of the if condition matches? thats the issue for you here.

Comment: Also check out `getDisplayName()` in the `Calendar` class. Not much sense to reinvent the wheel here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName%28int,%20int,%20java.util.Locale%29

Answer (score 5):

Sotirios is correct, but a better solution here would be to use a case statement:

```
switch(numericDayOfWeek)
{
    case 0:
      return "Saturday";
    case 1:
      return "Sunday";
    case 2:
      return "Monday";
    case 3:
      return "Tuesday";
    case 4:
      return "Wednesday";
    case 5:
      return "Thursday";
    case 6:
      return "Friday";
    default:
      return "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If none of the conditions passes, ie. they all evaluate to `false`, the method wouldn't return anything. Add a default return at the end

```
public String getDayOfWeek(){
     if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
         return "Saturday";
     }
     if(numericDayOfWeek==1){
         return "Sunday";
     }
     if(numericDayOfWeek==2){
         return "Monday";
     }
     if(numericDayOfWeek==3){
         return "Tuesday";
     }
     if(numericDayOfWeek==4){
        return "Wednesday";
     }
     if(numericDayOfWeek==5){
        return "Thursday";
     }
     if(numericDayOfWeek==6){
         return "Friday";
     }
     return "Error";
 }
```

The compiler considers all paths. If none if the `if` statements was executed it wouldn't have anything to `return`. In that case, it won't be able to compile because the method wouldn't guarantee the contract specified by its definition, ie. to return a `String`.

Follow the comments or the other answer on how to possibly makes this perform better or make it easier to read (`switch-case`).

Comment: I may add that numericDayOfWeek should be a parameter to your method.

Comment: @AleZalazar In the OP's question, it's an instance field.

Comment: I've seen it but I keep thinking the same way. What if you forget to call getNumericDayOfWeek() before getDayOfWeek()? At least you should be using a getter and lazy initialization.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public String getDayOfWeek(){
    if(numericDayOfWeek==0){
         return "Saturday";
    }
    else if(numericDayOfWeek==1){
        return "Sunday";
    }
    else if(numericDayOfWeek==2){
         return "Monday";
    }
    else if(numericDayOfWeek==3){
        return "Tuesday";
    }
    else if(numericDayOfWeek==4){
        return "Wednesday";
    }
    else if(numericDayOfWeek==5){
       return "Thursday";
    }
    else if(numericDayOfWeek==6){
        return "Friday";
    }
    else{
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't. You need a last `else`.

Comment: If the client doesn't do validation on the range of values `numericaDayOfWeek` takes, you will get `Friday` for value 1231231. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, i was trying to fix the compilation problem, and the use of the sentence `if-then-else` that is better than `if-then` in this case, because are exclusive comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the compiler error is that the compiler cannot be certain that your code will always return a String from your method.

In the event that numericDayOfWeek is not in the range of 0 to 6, your function does not specify what value should be returned, and there is no way for the compiler to know or guarantee that numericDayOfWeek will always be within the desired range.

Unfortunately, the compiler is limited in its ability to ensure a `return` statement even in simple cases.  Take the trivial (and useless) method below:

```
// I have a compiler error!
public boolean testReturn()
{
    final boolean condition = true;

    if (condition) return true;

    if (!condition) return false;
}
```

The above will result in a compiler error saying the method must return a type of boolean.  We could easily fix it by changing the second `if` statement to be an `else` clause since that is one of the few ways that allow the compiler to ensure one or the other blocks of code are guaranteed to be executed.

```
// I compile!
public boolean testReturn()
{
    final boolean condition = true;

    if (condition) return true
    else return false;
}
```

The rules are that a method with a return type must not complete *normally* and must instead complete *abruptly* (abruptly here indicating via a `return` statement or an exception) per [JLS 8.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7).  The compiler looks to see whether normal termination is possible based on the rules defined in [JLS 14.21 Unreachable Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) as it also defines the rules for normal completion.

In the case of your specific example, I would suggest considering throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` as the last line of your method and replacing your `if` statement with a `switch` statement.  E.g.

```
public String getDayOfWeek()
{
    switch(numericDayOfWeek)
    {
        case 0: return "Saturday";
        case 1: return "Sunday";
        case 2: return "Monday";
        case 3: return "Tuesday";
        case 4: return "Wednesday";
        case 5: return "Thursday";
        case 6: return "Friday";
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("numericDayOfWeek is out of range: " + numericDayOfWeek);
}
```

You can also throw the exception in a `default` clause of the `switch` statement, but in this case I would say that is just a matter of personal preference and I prefer outside of the `switch` here.